# How to pass a Javascript variable to the NAME attribute of an HTML <a href> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass a JavaScript variable to the NAME attribute of a HTML  tag. For example, say I had a script like this:

```
<script>
var name = "Click here!";
</script>
```

I then want to pass that to some code such that

```
<a href="www.google.com"><name></a>
```

would produce a link to google that was displayed as "Click here!"

Comment: `myElement.name = name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery it would look like this:

```
<a id="linkToGoogle" href="www.google.com"></a>
```

and in your script

```
$('#linkToGoogle').text('Click here!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the `<a>` tag, then add this to your script (script uses example ID *mylink*):

```
document.getElementById("mylink").innerHTML = name;
```

Add the ID like so:

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="mylink"></a>
```

Comment: @Gerard: Yes it does.
@Daniel: `.textContent` would be better in place of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="change-name"` to the elements that you want to change.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="change-name">This text will be replaced</a>
```

And then do:

```
var new_text = "Click here!";
var elems = document.querySelector('.change-name');
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].innerHTML = new_text;
}
```